# LIBGDX, ANDROID: deadlock killing app when when returning captured picture

Tags: java, android, libgdx, crash, deadlock

I have been trying for the past two or three days to build a program that allows the user to **take a picture** using the native camera or **pick one from the gallery**. After, getting a picture from either method, the picture is returned to the core libgdx project for processing. Picking from the gallery works like a charm. And the **take a picture** method, if returned as thumbnail it works perfectly.

However, I would like use a resized photo instead of a thumbnail. The application keeps crashing with "AndroidGraphics: deadlock kill" error. Code speaks louder than words.

```
public void takePicture() {
    selectedImagePath = null;
    selectedByteArray = null;

    /* when thumbnail
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_TAKEPICTURE_CODE);
    }
    */

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = timeStamp + ".jpg";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    pictureImagePath = storageDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + imageFileName;
    File file = new File(pictureImagePath);
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, SELECT_TAKEPICTURE_CODE);
}
```

Handling the activity.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED||data==null) {
        didUserCancel = true;
    }

    /* Also for the thumbnail use
    if (requestCode == SELECT_TAKEPICTURE_CODE&&resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        selectedByteArray = convertBitmapToByteArray(imageBitmap);
    }
    */

    if (requestCode == SELECT_TAKEPICTURE_CODE&&resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
        File imgFile = new File(pictureImagePath);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            pictureCaptured = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Three helper methods

```
private Bitmap scaleDownBitmap(Bitmap realImage, float maxImageSize, boolean filter) {
    float ratio = Math.min( maxImageSize / (float)realImage.getWidth(),
            maxImageSize / (float)realImage.getHeight());
    int width = Math.round( ratio * (float)realImage.getWidth());
    int height = Math.round( ratio * (float)realImage.getHeight());
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, width, height, filter);

    return newBitmap;
}

private byte[] convertBitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bmp, int quality) {
    if(quality>100)
        quality = 100;
    if(quality<0)
        quality = 0;

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

    return byteArray;
}

@Override
public byte[] getCapturedPictureAsByteArray(float imageSize, boolean smoothFilter, int quality) {
    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromPath(pictureImagePath);
    Bitmap scaledDownBitmap = scaleDownBitmap(bitmap, imageSize, smoothFilter);
    selectedByteArray = convertBitmapToByteArray(scaledDownBitmap, quality);

    return selectedByteArray;
}
```

Now for a rough version of the code on the core Game side:

```
if(gameMode==GameMode.setTextureFromCapturedPicture) {
        float imageSize = 100; boolean smoothFilter = true; int quality = 10;
        texture = byteArrayToTexture(rootApp.galleryOpener.getCapturedPictureAsByteArray(imageSize, smoothFilter, quality));
        gameMode = GameMode.play;
    }
```

For converting from byte[] to texture.

```
private Texture byteArrayToTexture(byte[] bytes) {
    try {
        Pixmap pmap =new Pixmap(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        Texture tex =new Texture(pmap);
        return tex;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

The error is I take a picture it takes me back to the libgdx's previous screen (in my case the menu screen). When I search the phone's Gallery I find that picture and can view it without issues. Furthermore, when I run my Game again, and chose that lastly picked picture, it works :s

The saddest part is that the error cannot be generated repeatedly. It just crashes. However, the most frequent errors I am getting are

```
com.*.*.game/Zygote: v2
com.*.*.game E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
```

OR

```
com.*.*.game waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is this; Tell the intent where you want to store the image from the camera, otherwise nothing is stored:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_FOLDER + File.separator + "temp_image.jpg");
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                            takePictureIntent.putExtra(PhotoStatics.OUTPUT_FORMAT, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
                            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, PhotoStatics.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

And then we listen for when the photo is done, and grab it from the place we told the camera to store the image...

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    //System.out.println("onActivityResult = " + requestCode + " " + resultCode + " " + intent.getAction());

    // Photo incoming
    if (requestCode == PhotoStatics.REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { // check if we have something to work with

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_FOLDER + File.separator + "temp_image.jpg");
            Uri image_uri = Uri.fromFile(file); // get where the temp is stored
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_uri.getPath());
        }
    }
}
```

Does this make sense to you?

```
// Static Globals
public static final String TEMP_IMAGE = "temp_image";
public static final String OUTPUT_FORMAT = "outputFormat";
public static final String IMAGE_FOLDER = "/these_pictures"; // don't forget the / at the beginning.
public static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 12; // just internal use.
public static final String IMAGE_TYPE = ".jpg";
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will test it and get back to you!

Comment: What's PhotoStatics.OUTPUT_FORMAT?

Comment: Added the statics I use.

Comment: Thanx again for the clear up. I tested it, but it still isn't working : (